# Cannot find Google VR sdk in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I am trying to learn VR app development with Cardboard and Unity. So when I was installing the sample according to reference below: https://developers.google.com/vr/unity/get-started
I could not find Cardboard in VR SDKs after I enabled VR supported. There are only three items: Oculus, Split Stereo Display, None. Can anyone help me on this? My unity version is 5.4.2f2 personal. Thanks!

Comment: Have you simply tried with "Split Stereo Display" ? Basically, The Google cardboard is nothing more than this.

Comment: Thanks. I will have a try.